# values argument of the variable_scope

Tags: tensorflow

Could someone shed some light on the 
 **values** 
argument of the **variable_scope** Class
in tensorflow. The official documentation is a little bit confusing.

I m quoting from the doc:

> This context manager validates that the (optional) values are from the same graph, ensures that graph is the default graph, and pushes a name scope and a variable scope.

and

> values: The list of Tensor arguments that are passed to the op function.

Can anyone present a use case of such an argument ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at source code in the current 1.7.0 version ([`python/ops/variable_scope.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.7.0/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py)), its use seems somewhat niche. The only thing that parameter appears to be used for is to call the internal function `_get_graph_from_inputs` (defined in [`python/framework/ops.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.7.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py)), which returns the graph on which the operations are to be constructed (the graph for which you are creating the scope, I understand). When you don't pass anything, it will be the current default graph, when you give some tensors, the graph in which these live is used. I find hard to imagine a case in which one would prefer to pass some values instead of setting a default graph context, but there it is... Maybe it is used internally or something else, but I would not be surprised if they decide to deprecate the parameter at some point, since I have not been able to find a single usage example.